# I need help figuring out how to get a connected user from the web3modal button and accept an eth transaction using just vanilla js

Tags: wallet-connect

I was using the walletconnect version 1 up until recently until the support stopped and i was forced to use the version 2 and so far it hasnt been a pleasant adaptation i am having issues with sending an eth transaction to a connected account through the

in a seperate function i connect to a metamask account using the metamask connector and i am able to send transactions but when i try to use the walletconnectconnector it doesnt work
i would appreciate any help in either updating my code or giving an entirely new code --ps with some explanations

and lastly i would add that i didnt use any js libraries just vanilla js and importing the modules through cdn

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <w3m-core-button></w3m-core-button>
    <button id="send">Send</button>

    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my Js file

```
import {
  EthereumClient,
  w3mConnectors,
  w3mProvider,
  WagmiCore,
  WagmiCoreChains,
  WagmiCoreConnectors,
} from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/ethereum@2.6.2";

import { Web3Modal } from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/html@2.6.2";

// 0. Import wagmi dependencies
const { mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum } = WagmiCoreChains;
const { configureChains, createConfig } = WagmiCore;

// 1. Define chains
const chains = [mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum];
const projectId = "2aca272d18deb10ff748260da5f78bfd";

// 2. Configure wagmi client
const { publicClient } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: [
    ...w3mConnectors({ chains, version: 2, projectId }),
    new WagmiCoreConnectors.CoinbaseWalletConnector({
      chains,
      options: {
        appName: "html wagmi example",
      },
    }),
  ],
  publicClient,
});

// 3. Create ethereum and modal clients
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains);
export const web3Modal = new Web3Modal(
  {
    projectId,
    walletImages: {
      safe: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1566773491764023297/IvmCdGnM_400x400.jpg",
    },
  },
  ethereumClient
);

document.querySelector("#send").addEventListener('click', function(){
  send()
})
async function send(){
  const result = await connect({
    chains: [mainnet],
    connector : new WalletConnectConnector({
    options: {
      projectId : '53ba3da3113927c74d5df66e383ed2ac'
    }
  })
    // connector : new MetaMaskConnector()
  }).then((result)=>{
    const { hash } = sendTransaction({
      to: '0x5b01D1B08A6c26682996c318E6cB28d13bD87Ad2',
      value: '0x174876E800',
  })
  })
}
```

The send button is able to connect to metamask account and initiate the send transaction method but i cant replicate the same effect for an account connect through the w3button

Answer (score 2):

Your code has helped me successfully migrate from `Walletconnect` v1 to v2 and call transactions all in Vanilla JavaScript using both viem and [wagmi actions](https://wagmi.sh/react/actions)

You should initiate Web3Modal in your send() function. It will help trigger the transaction on supported wallets including Metamask.

```
Import needed viem and wagmi actions/dependencies.
import { parseEther } from "https://esm.sh/viem";
const { configureChains, createConfig, sendTransaction } = WagmiCore;
```

Then your `send()` function should look like

```
async function send(){
    const result = web3Modal.openModal()
        .then((result)=>{
        const { hash } = sendTransaction({
        to: '0x5b01D1B08A6c26682996c318E6cB28d13bD87Ad2',
        value: parseEther(0.01),
        })
    })
}
```